# Putting a touch motions into variable

Tags: java, javascript, android

I wanted to put the Android touch motions of touching down, dragging, and lifting up all into separate variables. My goal is to use them in JavaScript in place of the mouse movements ~ 'mousedown', 'mousemove', and 'mouseup'. Which is why I need them in variables in Java to send over. I'm new to Java so I don't know what to do with that part. Any examples or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is what I have, but don't know what to do with it and I need the other movements also (up and down touches):

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
        }
      });
```

Comment: have you tried any thing yet ?

Comment: A couple of things, but I'm pretty much totally lost. =/

Comment: update your question and post what you have tried so far

Comment: You can compare them as events. Why do you need to put them on variables?

Comment: I'm trying to use Google Chromecast. Which as far as I know needs a variable to send information over to the Chromecast device from the android device. And I wanted to use each touch motion separately. Maybe I'm totally wrong though.